# UITableView sections order not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7

I am using a tableView with customised section titles. Everything is working as expected, but the order of the sections is not responding as I expected. This is the dictionary data I am using. In my desired sequence I want "upcoming" as 1st and "Attended" as 2nd section but order which it is showing is completely opposite to this.

```
tableSection = @{@"Upcoming" : @[@"Amit", @"Vatsala", @"Jasmine",     @"Jasmine", @"Jasmine"],
                 @"Attended" : @[@"Kritarth", @"Rahul"] };
```

Please suggest some help!!

```
#pragma mark - UITableView delegate    
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [tableSection count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 150;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section {
    return 25;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSString *sectionTitle = [tableSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionAnimals = [tableSection objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return [sectionAnimals count];
} 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    AppointmentTableCell *cell = (AppointmentTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AppointmentTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    //Configure the cell...
    NSString *sectionTitle = [tableSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionArray = [tableSection objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.doctorImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"doctor.png"];
    [cell.nameLabel setFont:FONT_OPENSANS_LIGHT(14)];

        return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? All of your tableView-delegate methods would be a good start

Comment: I tried the same code after removing the array. Still it is giving me the same order of sections.

Comment: Sorry I removed my comment and just made it an answer. Was the order of tableSectionTitles in the order you wanted? It should just be a matter of making sure that is in the correct order and the rest should have fallen into place.

Comment: `NSArray *sectionArray = [tableSection objectForKey:sectionTitle];` **A dictionary does not have a defined order.**

Comment: That I know. But still I am facing this issue thats why I posted this here.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have an array separately only for the titles of the `Table View`?

```
_arrayTitles = @[@"Upcoming",@"Attended"];
```

And one array that contains two arrays for the `Sections data source`:

```
NSArray *arraySectionOne=@[@"Amit", @"Vatsala", @"Jasmine", @"Jasmine", @"Jasmine"];
NSArray *arraySectionTwo=@[@"Kritarth", @"Rahul"];
_dataSource=@[arraySectionOne, arraySectionTwo];
```

And in the '`viewForHeaderInSection`' you set the titles from this array:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    YourHeaderView *headerView=nil;

    headerView=[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"YourHeaderView"];
    headerView.titleHeader.text = _arrayTitles[section];
    return headerView;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return _arrayTitles.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSMutableArray *arraySection=_dataSource[section];
    return arraySection.count;
}
```

Comment: That is because currently I have only 2 arrays but in future this number is going to increase by 5-10. In that case using 10 different arrays is not good.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are actually getting the title from a separate array called tableSectionTitles and because you use the string in that array to get all your row information it would explain why the order would be different. I don't see tableSectionTiltles array in the code you supplied but my best guess would be that is where the issue is actually coming from.

**EDIT**

As you stated in comments the tableSectionTitles is actually an array coming from [tableSection allKeys]; Because NSDictionary doesn't actually have an oder that array comes in whatever order it wants. You can fix this in two ways.

Manually put the keys of the dictionary in this array in the oder you want but that would be less scaleable.

Create a NSObject subclass with a titleString and rowStringsArray (name this something better to what you are building your app for) and then add those objects to an array and use that to generate your table.

I hope that helps.

Comment: tableSection = @{@"Upcoming" : @[@"Amit", @"Vatsala", @"Jasmine", @"Jasmine", @"Jasmine"],
                     @"Attended" : @[@"Kritarth", @"Rahul"] };
    tableSectionTitles = [tableSection allKeys];

Here is the description of tableSectionTitles array.

Comment: That would be the issue there allKeys I have run into this issue before too. You would expect it to come back in the order you build a NSDictionary, but NSDictionary doesn't actually have an order. I will update my answer to include to other solutions you may want to consider.

Answer (score 0):

The way to build a fully general-purpose dataSource is this:

- Have an outermost `sections` NSMutableArray.
- For each section insert an NSMutableDictionary.
- Insert a "title" (string) element in the dictionary for the section title.
- Insert an NSMutableArray in the dictionary with the key "rows".
- For each row create an NSMutableDictionary to contain the actual data for that table row (and insert it into the "rows" array, of course).

You can add other elements to the per-section dictionary as needed, of course, and if you're one of those who gets their shorts in a knot about efficiency you can replace the dictionaries with purpose-made objects.

For a single-section table forgo the `sections` array and the per-section dictionary.